# Update IE Doc Mode to latest version using script/ Tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, internet-explorer

I have a requirement to update IE mode to latest version. How to know the latest version of IE using script?

I can use META tag but in meta tag we need to mention the browser version. If i mention the browser version as IE9, what if the end user user browser version is IE8?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

I want to know the end user browser version and set the doc mode (If the user browser version is IE8/IE9, set doc mode as IE8/IE9)

how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

The value `edge` means "using as recent a version as possible".